# Element with fixed position get drifted during scrolling in iOS homescreen web app

Tags: html, ios, css-position

I have a menu with a fixed position

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <title>My App</title>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    .parent {
      position: relative;
      max-height: 100vh;
      padding-top: 3rem;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
    .menu {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      background: pink;
      text-align: center;
      height: 3rem;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <nav class="menu">Menu</nav>
    <div style="height:100vh; background: yellow">1</div>
    <div style="height:100vh; background: green">2</div>
    <div style="height:100vh; background: red">3</div>
  <div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/xojarekano

On mobile safari, you can scroll and the menu stick to the top, as expected.

But if you add to home screen, and then launch the site from there, when you scroll, the menu get drifted, disappears then appear again. I have tried adding `translateZ(1px)` into the menu class but the problem still exists.

Why does this behave differently when it's launched from home screen as opposed to inside mobile safari. How can be this fixed?